# Avoiding false positives in javascript tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm developing a jQuery plugin which cycles through a number of images. I'm writing some tests and want to test that the src attribute is always being changed when it should be. The trouble is that

- the original image is included in the list of images to cycle through
- the image to be used in the page is chosen at random
- the cycle is controlled by setInterval which, due to system performance etc., is a bit unpredictable

So sometimes it's possible that the test will fail due to the original image being randomly chosen from those available, thus looking like a change didn't occur.

How can I avoid false positives like these?

Comment: Doing a simple filename (of the image that is currently loaded) comparison?

Answer (score 1):

As we are in JavaScript you can overwrite Math.random like this:

```
describe('some suite', function () {

  it('Math.random should equal 1', function () {
      var origRandom = Math.prototype.random;
      Math.prototype.random = function(){return 1};
      expect(Math.random()).toEqual(1);
      Math.prototype..random = origRandom;
  });

it('Math.random should equal 1 using jasmine', function () {
      spyOn(Math, 'random').andReturn(1)
      expect(Math.random()).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

Another way is to pass the random number to you render function instead of creating there inside the function you wanna test

Comment: I like this idea, but am a bit nervous about using it in case a method called by the method I'm testing calls Math.random too

Comment: Using random in test isn't a good idea anyway. Take a look at this post: http://blog.tuxychandru.com/2009/11/mocking-mathrandom-using-powermock.html. It Java but they does the same `EasyMock.expect(Math.random()).andReturn(0.50).anyTimes();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jasmine Spy behaviour](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Spies) to check that your method is being called. In particular `spyMethod.callcount` which you can use to check the number of times a method has been called.

For example. Something like this:

```
var cycleMethod = SpyOn(jQPlugin.theCycleMethod).andCallThrough();

waits(1000);

runs(function() {

    expect(cycleMethod.callCount).toEqual(2);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery toggle() to add a class when you make the change, then search for the class you've added.  Calling toggle will add a class if it doesn't exist and remove if it does, so it will be set if you're supposed to have a new image, and not if you're supposed to have the original.

Comment: The trouble is that this will add a bit of unrequired functionality to the plugin

Comment: It's useful as a testing and debugging tool.  You can use prefixed data attributes if you're concerned about interrelation with other code. http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I take special care to make my design as modular as possible, so I can test all the bits and pieces separately.  Sounds like you should do the same.  That way, things like the behavior of `setInterval` have less or no impact on your tests.

For example, you should have dedicated method for choosing the next URL, that you can test independently from the rest of the code.  For the purposes of that method, you don't care if the original image is in the list, because for the test you set the list of images to be whatever you want.  In the test, I would invoke the method multiple times, storing the results of each invocation, and then I would assert that the same string is not in every result.

Comment: I'm not sure this methodology can apply here. I do have a function which carries out changing the url but it's not a public method by design (I only make a plugin's method public if I think it's likely a user will want to customise it, which normally excludes core functionality).

Comment: its javascript...are you really making things 'private'?

Comment: because of the problem you are having now